# Force pushed to wrong repo, cleaning up artefacts

Tags: git, controls, version, push

We have an unstable repository where we constantly rebase and force push until we upstream.

I accidentally pushed to the wrong remote. This was quickly fixed, by force pushing the old history back. But I understand that Git keeps a history, and now I see that commit hashes can be checked out when they should not be in this repository at all. I tried to git push --delete origin master and then git push --force origin +master to repopulate the repository, but I'm still seeing irrelevant commit hashes (not in the history, but directly accessible via GitHub). I'd like to get rid of these to reduce the size of our repo.

Cheers

Comment: You want to run something like `git prune` or `git gc` on the remote repo. If this repo is on a server you control, you can ssh there, go to the appropriate folder, and run the command. I'm trying to look if there is some way to trigger this without ssh-ing to the server.

Comment: warning : read `git help prune / git help gc` before you do something irreversible ... `git prune --dry_run` is a safe start.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My tree is on GitHub. Looks like git prune --dry_run has quite a few suggestions; will I need to force push after this, and will this break the tree for others?

Comment: I've just read that I'll need to re-create my repository. Thanks for your help. I'll definitely use git prune or git gc (which is more conservative) on our self-hosted repos

Comment: One other thing to check : make a fresh clone of the "tainted" remote, and see if, in your local clone, you have the references of the undesirable files.  
If the files are unreachable, they shouldn't be downloaded.